# Automatic EQ creation to get similar frequence response from two sources?

Tags: audio-recording, frequency, eq

Is there some kind of plugin / tool (preferably ladspa, lv2 or at least open source) to compare two recordings of an identical source, done with two different mics & recorders and create an automatic EQ setting to make one as similar as possible to the other?

Comment: I'm not sure this isn't going to be too 'opinion-based' for SE, but this has a lively discussion on the subject - https://www.gearslutz.com/board/mastering-forum/644921-best-eq-cloning-replicating-spectrums.html However, no EQ is going to make up for environmental differences, different room reverbs etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and actually I think my case its easier and more reasonable than what the threadstarter on the forum you linked asked for. Of course you cannot replicate an eq setting for a an entire mix and hope it sounds similar, what I am talking about is a different case though since I only want to match two different mic's

Comment: Yes, the 'match one track against another' idea is a non-starter really; your task should be a whole lot simpler, but the suggested tools are going to be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I'd mess try Dynamic Spectrum Mapper, iZotope Ozone EQ (that has a matching eq setting) and possibly Logic's Match EQ.